# Elisp search and delete

Tags: search, text

Interspersed in a text file I have
`0:36Skip to 0 minutes and 36 seconds  blah blah`,
always at the beginning of a line.
I am looking for a function to search and delete these. Failing, I have

```el
(defun mddtt ()
  (interactive)
  (re-search-forward "[0-9]:")
  (goto-char (line-beginning-position))
  (push-mark nil 1 t)
  (search-forward "seconds")
  (setq st (pop-mark))
  (setq en (point))
  (delete-region st en))
```

The error is `mddtt: Wrong type argument: integer-or-marker-p, nil`
(not sure where).

I'm running this manually, I will introduce checking for failed searches, but I'm happy just to exit the function.

Improvements pleas?

Comment: "not sure where [the error is]" - try instrumenting with [edebug](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Edebug.html) (`C-u C-M-x`) and stepping through.

Comment: Also, look at the docstring of `set-mark` (mentioned from `push-mark`) where it says "Novice Emacs Lisp programmers often try to use the mark for the wrong
purposes", this applies to your case.

Comment: The error is signaled by `delete-region` because the value of `st` is `nil`.  The reason is that `pop-mark` is only used for its side effects; it is not expected to return a value.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. Now solved: solution below meets my needs.

(defun mddtt ()
  """ Delete time marker in future learn video scripts
Use C-x z, z to repeat """
  (interactive)
  (re-search-forward "[0-9]:")
  (goto-char (line-beginning-position))
  (setq st (point) )
  (search-forward "seconds")
  (setq en (point))
  (message (number-to-string en))
   (delete-region st en))

Answer (score 5):

[Search and replace](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Replace.html#Replace) already exists in Emacs!

```
C-M-% ^.*?[0-9]:.*?seconds RET RET .
```

`C-M-%` invokes [`query-replace-regexp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Query-Replace.html#index-query_002dreplace_002dregexp). You enter a regular expression, then the replacement text (empty). The final `.` says to perform one replacement only, you can press `Y` instead to replace all remaining occurrences, `y` or `n` to replace the current occurrence or not and move to the next one without stopping search-and-replace, etc.

The [regular expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html) I wrote mimics what you do:

- start at the beginning of a line (`^`);
- skip to the first occurrence of a digit followed by a colon (`.*?` uses a shortest-match repeat operator so it stops at the first occurrence of what follows, `.*` would skip to the last digit-colon that's followed by `seconds` on the same line);
- skip to the first subsequent occurrence of `seconds`;
- the whole match is deleted since the replacement text is empty.

In a Lisp program, you can write `(replace-regexp "^.*?[0-9]:.*?seconds" "")` to replace all occurrences from the point to the end of the buffer, but as the documentation of `replace-regexp` tells you, most of the work of `replace-regexp` is related to its interactive use, and in Lisp you're encouraged to write your own loop:

```
(while (re-search-forward "^.*?[0-9]:.*?seconds")
  (replace-match "" nil nil))
```

If you wanted to replace just one occurrence (like your function), that would be

```
(if (re-search-forward "^.*?[0-9]:.*?seconds")
    (replace-match "" nil nil))
```

Writing nontrivial Lisp code would be needed if your search pattern was too complex to be recognized by a regular expression. When you write Lisp code, don't use the mark: that's a user-level feature which is rarely appropriate for internal use. To store a position in a buffer, use a [local variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Local-Variables.html#Local-Variables) defined by [`let`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Local-Variables.html#index-let). Always use `let` to define variables that you use locally in a function, otherwise your calls to `setq` pollute global variables. The current position is [`(point)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Point.html#index-point-1); this is a number that doesn't change if the buffer is subsequently modified. If you need a location that tracks when text is inserted or removed before it — which is not the case here — use a [marker](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Markers.html#Markers).

```
(defun mddtt ()
  (interactive "@*")
  (re-search-forward "[0-9]:")
  (let ((st (line-beginning-position)))
    (search-forward "seconds")
    (delete-region st (point))))
```

To summarize:

- Look for built-in features before reinventing the wheel.
- Use `let` for local variables.
- Don't use the mark for internal purposes.